# A full count with no criteria

Tags: grails

In grails, I can get all the Person with a certain criteria by doing:

```
def possibleUsers = Person.withCriteria {
    ...
}
```

But I just want to count all persons - I don't have a criteria.

What is the Grails way to do this?

thanks

Comment: The docs is your friend...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe

```
Person.count()
```

[should do it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/count.html)